# when we windows version it gives 6.3 for both windows 8.1 or windows server 2012 R2. How to distinguish between them?

Tags: windows-8

By using environment API we got version of windows. but 6.3 is shown for both windows 8.1 and windows server 2012 R2.

Please suggest some code by using environment variable how to distinguish between them.

Comment: You should show us the code you've written already so we can see what you're doing. Also, you haven't told us anything about the language you're working in. How can we help you without knowing that?

Comment: I m working on c# language. For finding version i am using Environment API. after that this code i m using but according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724832(v=vs.85).aspx this web site both(windows 8.1 and windows server 2012 R2) are showing 6.3. how i m dintinguish bewen them.

Comment: switch (ver.Major)
            {
                case 6:
                    if (ver.Minor == 0)
                        
                        op = "Microsoft Windows Vista";
                        else
                            op = "Windows Server 2008";
                    else if (ver.Minor == 1)
                        op = "Microsoft Windows 7";
                    else if (ver.Minor == 2)
                        op = "Microsoft Windows 8";
                    else if (ver.Minor == 3)
                        op = "Microsoft Windows 8.1";

                    break;

Comment: please edit the question to include those details; it's harder to read as a comment, plus editing it will bring the question back to attention so you're more likely to get some answers.

Answer (score 0):

check if `VER_NT_WORKSTATION == OSversion.wProductType`,
if yes it is windows 8, if no it is server 2012.

note than GetVersionEx supports up to windows 8, for win 8.1 or 10 you will get back ver 6.2